# Looking at ideas for an "incorporated" logo for my fictitious company

Tags: logo

For school, I have to create a logo for a fictitious company I create. The company name I have been given is "Smash" or "Smash Games". It is supposed to be a gaming company similar to Activision or Electronic Arts. I had a couple ideas, but I cannot seem to properly incorporate them, and I'm not really "proud" of these designs either. I am fairly certain I want to include a fist somewhere in the logo, but this is not completely necessary. I need help brainstorming some clever ideas for my logo before I create it. I would really love your creative minds. I will post my (BAD (I cannot draw/sketch for my life)) sketches below.
[image: (Bad) Sketch #1:]

[image: (Bad) Sketch #2:]

Comment: Hi Bert, we don't do project-specific brainstorming here, maybe somewhere like http://deviantart.com might be better? A few general tips though: never be self-conscious about how rough idea sketches are, they're for your own use so they can be as rough as you like! And for making things look like letters - people recognise words as whole units not letter-by-letter so people will already be ready for an `m` shape there: it's not far off working already. Just make sure the three middle fingers are prominent, clear and mostly vertical, like the uprights of an `m`.

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry about that. I won't do it again.

Comment: No need to apologise! Hope it goes well :)

Comment: The fist idea is a great one! You mention you want it to resemble an M. Something we *can* help with are [drawing questions](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drawing). Why not open a new one with the last image, and a request for ideas on how to improve the M-shape of the fist?  :)

Answer (score 2):

Before you start working on the logo, make some notes about your fictitious company.

Who is your target audience? Are you making games for kids? -> colorful, funny

for adults? -> Exactly the opposite

for everyone? -> Neutral design

What games are you making? Sport games? -> dynamic, young

Strategy games? -> sophisticated

What is your company about? High quality, complexity -> professional, luxurious

Easy to play, cheap -> friendly

After that you can start thinking about font, image, etc.
For example a fist stands for aggression, action, riot (see Riot Games). Does that identify your company?

Just think about the identity of your company A LOT before you start the drawing. ;)

Comment: This is actually pretty helpful. I was thinking it would be geared towards adults, with focus on open world story based games. It's meant to be high quality. That is why I chose the fist.

Comment: A fist isn't really what I would link with high quality. But hey, there you go, story-based open-world games for adults! You can also look at other companys that make exactly these games for some inspiration. ;)